# How can I determine the maximum GPU texture size in AIR for iOS?

Tags: ios, air

I'm using cacheAsBitmap and cacheAsBitmapMatrix on large images in AIR 3.3 for iOS. Older hardware has a 2048x2048 GPU texture size limit, the New iPad (3) has 4096x4096. Is there a way to check for this size limit in code, instead of linking the code to specific existing models?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I could develop one, but wouldn't want to waste my time if there is already one built into Stage3D.